# Passing request object to different servlet/action of same application running at different servers

Tags: java, servlets, struts

Hi I have one application running on different servers build in struts2 and deployed in Tomcat5. Now I have a functionality of "Save on All" in this application. When it is called, then the same request parameters need to be passed to all the servlet/action of all the applications running in all the servers. How can this be done?

---

E.g. I have 5 servers in LAN, each having independent tomcat & mysql. The application is deployed in each tomcat. Now if I upload an image from application running on any server, it should be uploaded to all the servers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like the [Apache HttpClient library](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html). However, beware: depending on your application, a failure on just one of several servers may leave things in a weird state. I'd test this thoroughly if I were you, including by unplugging network cables.

Comment: does struts provide any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution lies entirely elsewhere. You certainly do **not** want to solve it at the webinterface level. You need to solve it at the server software level. The application servers needs to run in a clustered environment, all sharing the same data. Here's the Tomcat 5.5 document which describes how to do it: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/cluster-howto.html

Similar exist for database servers, but as you didn't mention if and if so which one you're using I can't give a link to detailed documentation how to do it. You now at least know the search keyword *"cluster"*.

Good luck.

Comment: I think u r not getting my point. I have 5 servers in LAN, each having independent tomcat & mysql. Now if I upload an image from application running on any server, it should be uploaded to all the servers.

Comment: Then cluster the webservers AND databaseservers.

Answer (score 0):

From your further comments, I think you're going about this entirely the wrong way. If you need an image, don't duplicate it; make a simple service that stores images and call it from your other apps. This is known as a [service-oriented architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-Oriented_Architecture). (Under that name, you'll hear a lot of enterprise blah-blah; ignore that, and the SOA products out there. Just make a simple app that lets you POST pictures and GET them again later.)